# Cleanest way for conditional rendering to satisfy flow

Tags: javascript, flowtype

I am adding flow to existing code. I have many places where conditional rendering is used: eg

```
import React from "react";

export default function App() {
  let visible = true;
  return (
    visible && (
      <div className="App">
        <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      </div>
    )
  );
}
```

adding flow I get the error `inexact boolean [1] is incompatible with exact React.Element`

I can understand why flow is unhappy -relying on the shortcircuit operator seems really hokey to me. I don't really like this code myself, but what is the cleanest way for me to get around the error and keep flow happy?  I am trying to avoid lots of ifs.

TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For readability try not using ternary operators. Return early if you know you can.

```
import React from "react";

export default function App({visible}) {
  if (!visible) {
    return null;
  }

  return (
      <div className="App">
        <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using the ternary operator? I am not familiar with React, so I can't guarantee that this would produce the same result that your code does with that framework.

```
import React from "react";

export default function App() {
  let visible = true;
  return (
    visible ? (
      <div className="App">
        <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      </div>
    ) : null // return whatever you need to there
  );
}
```

Comment: thanks for the input, but no, sadly it doesn't satisfy flow, because we are still comparing different kinds of types boolean, react element and null.  error here is ```Cannot return `visible ? (<div className="App">   <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>    </div>  ) : null` because inexact null [1] is incompatible with exact `React.Element` [2].```

Answer (score 0):

This seems odd. What version of flow were you using? I've used this style countless times but haven't seen an issue. I even plugged this into try-flow and there's no problems. I'm wondering if this was an error you were getting on the consuming component or the `App` component?

https://flow.org/try/#0JYWwDg9gTgLgBAKjgQwM5wEoFNkGN4BmUEIcARFDvmQNwBQdBArgHb7AQtwCCYYAFAEoAXJiowAdADkIAEyxwA3nThwANlngA3YKmAAjDXAC8cGFCZZ6qyjCZQu-Farg69hhQDJPcJy5cAPLLAWnC4amioUsggWMZkvGBkAHzO-qoBABYAjMkAElhqahBwAMJyWADKyCyy+hAAHgEA9Dmp6XAtwVrtLoLOgvQAvgy4nKjw3CwQMJlYUOXgJr4iYniSMvImyUppcLb2jnv+QSG9HSeJcM3n6V1ne4N0QzRAA